# Need help with a printer. (HP C4580)

Tags: 14.04, printing

I've been trying to get my printer set up (HP Photosmart c4580) and I got the HP software on but when I try to print out a page, no matter what, it just freezes on pending yet it doesn't have a problem cancelling. Is there something I can run in the command line to fix the problem? I tried finding a download firmware option but nothing. When I check the device info, I get fw-download false. I already have HPLIP.

Comment: Do you have the hplip toolbox (hplip-gui)? This may give you some more information.

Comment: Yeah turns out all I needed to do was delete and re add the printer. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Okay, Okay, I get it. Not many people know the power of Ubuntu. Ubuntu can print from literally *ANY* printer without needing to install loads of software. The drivers probably are causing the problem. You may need to delete them. If the printer is over a windows network, you need to install samba. Installation steps for samba are [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/). After that you should be good!

Comment: I figured it out. All I needed to do was delete the printer and re add the device

Comment: Well crap. I posted a question and got nothing out of it. That's happened before D:

Comment: I'm still new to Ubuntu so I can really be much help right now. :/

Comment: meh. it's okay. If you have problems, though, I'll answer them for you! Chech my profile to see what i've answered for proof.

Comment: Haha I see. Definitely! See when you're asking about stuff like root, I have no idea how to do that.